# robot goes straight to the goal when it is at its left, but always rotates in the wrong direction when the goal is at its right

Tags: navigation, odometry, laser, amcl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a non holonomic robot, a neato XV-11 base equipped with an asus xtion pro live (kinect equivalent).

I have set up the navigation stack, and am using TrajectoryPlannerROS as a base local planner, with DWA set to true.

The path planning and obstacle inflation work good (as can be seen in RViz), but when it moves my robot shows a weird behavior:

Lets say the robot is pointing towards some direction. If I set the goal in rviz somewhere further but on the left side of the robot, it goes straight to the goal,
with a tendency to overturn a bit too much on the left while doing so. Then when the goal is reached, it rotates correctly to head to the goal direction.

But when I set the goal somewhere further but on the right side, the robot will not start to advance or turn towards the goal immediately, it would slowly turn in the wrong direction (so rotating to the left) until it makes a full turn and then starts to move, and reaches the goal correctly.

So it seems that all movements tend to overturn to the left.

I have checked all my transforms (is the laser transform from the base positionned correctly? and so on...), I have also checked the odometry (sending simple goals like moving forward 1 meter, and checking the rostopic echo output of /odom) but did not found anything wrong.

AMCL also seems to work nicely, as the laser more or less always catches the contour of the given map.

I'd be glad and thankful to your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82676/robot-goes-straight-to-the-goal-when-it-is-at-its-left,-but-always-rotates-in-the-wrong-direction-when-the-goal-is-at-its-right/) by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok it was a problem of base local planner parameters, I could not pinpoint the exact ones yet, but probably velocity/acceleration constraints. I copied the base local planner parameters from a previous configuration, and now it works.

---

Originally posted by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) with karma: 141 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmiraJr](https://answers.ros.org/users/19987/amirajr/) on 2014-08-10**:
Hello @micmac , I have the same problem, can you please share the configuration file